# How to remove/hide GitExtensions toolbar from Visual Studio?

Tags: git, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, git-extensions

I tried:

- right-click on a toolbar and uncheck GitExtensions
- right-click on a toolbar > Customize and delete GitExtensions
- moved the toolbar from the second row to the first row
- searched GitExtensions settings for a way to disable/hide the toolbar, but didn't find anything

The GitExtensions toolbar shows up again on the second toolbar row after a computer restart.

I use:

- Windows 8
- Visual Studio 2012
- Git 1.7.11
- GitExtensions 2.41

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Git Extension files are stored in your 'My Documents' folder in a "Visual Studio 2012" subfolder. Removing these files will make the toolbar disappear from within MSVC.

Comment: More specifically, they're under "Addins".  Two .dlls with gitplugins in the name.  Kill those and the annoying context menu stuff goes away next time you restart vs.net.

Comment: My 2 cents in case somebody came across the same bug and was pointed here by some googling.
This extension was the cause of random fatal crashes of visual studio 2010/2013. Event log say "Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.18408"

Removing this extension makes thing works again

Comment: Confirmed this also works for Visual Studio 2013.  These files in the Addins folder were crashing my Visual Studio constantly when trying to open the program.

Answer (score 28):

1. Run Git Extensions uninstaller from Control Panel
2. Click to 'Change' button
3. Deselect "Visual Studio extension" feature

**UPDATE**

This should work with 2.48.04 and newer versions: right-click on a toolbar, uncheck GitExtensions, close all VS instances and start it again.

Comment: Unchecking the GitExtensions toolbar hid the toolbar, but I still had to delete the files from the addins directory to get the context menu items to go away. The uninstaller method didn't work for me because it showed that the VS extension was uninstalled, even though it was installed.

Answer (score 2):

The location is correct, the file is called CurrentSettings.vssettings

I modified the line:

```
<add_toolbar Menu="{000D7B18-CDE4-49F0-B194-FE3E25BBF096}:00000002" 
 Name="GitExtensions" MenuType="toolbar" />
```

by adding  Visibility="hide" FullScreen="hide"

Result:

```
<add_toolbar Menu="{000D7B18-CDE4-49F0-B194-FE3E25BBF096}:00000002" 
 Name="GitExtensions" MenuType="toolbar"
 Visibility="hide" FullScreen="hide"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Deleting or changing the settings files (C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings) is only a temporary fix because Visual Studio recreates/overwrites this file each time you update a setting or close Visual Studio.

Using a team settings file doesn't work either because that file won't overwrite a parameter that's not in listed in the CurrentSettings.vssettigs file.  And it won't be listed in the CurrentSettings.vssettigs file after you close Visual Studio and the file gets regenerated.

* I see 3 options ***

**1. Recompile GitExtensions with the modification noted here:** https://github.com/gencer/gitextensions/commit/faef52e8191fde54ef9787f6f5156cf315ec9be5
This is not easy because the project includes a bunch of third party libraries that have to be installed and configured.  Good Luck!

**2. Use this .dll that was fixed by someone else.**
http://mirror.nienbo.com/git-extensions/patch_for_244/GitPlugin.dll
After you download it, right click on it, select properties, and press the "unblock" button.  Then copy it to C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins (overwriting the current file). This worked great for me.

**3. Use a different git extension program.**

Answer (score 1):

Resetting all settings worked for me. *Though, after that I had to set everything up from scratch*.

If that's not a problem then go to visual studio **TOOLS** > **Import and Export Settings...**> **Reset all Settings**.

I think it takes effect after restarting visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The settings for the Visual Studio Git Extensions toolbar can be found in this file:

> \Users{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings

Search the file for the term GitExtensions to find the toolbar setting lines. There will likely be two lines, not necessarily next to each other:

`<add_toolbar Menu="{000D7B18-CDE4-49F0-B194-FE3E25BBF096}:00000002" Name="GitExtensions" MenuType="toolbar"/>`

`<modify_toolbar Menu="{000D7B18-CDE4-49F0-B194-FE3E25BBF096}:00000002" Name="GitExtensions" Visibility="show" FullScreen="hide" Dock="top" Row="2" FloatRectangle="0,0,208,24" DockRectangle="0,0,208,24"/>`

You'll want to modify the second of the two lines, since it will take precedence, and it already has the settings in it.

You can set the Visibility to "auto" to make it behave like other toolbars, or "hide" to just get rid of it. Set the Row to 1 if you want it to stick to the first row of toolbars.

Of course you'll have to do this with VS closed in order for it to work properly.

Answer (score -2):

Please make sure you remove .git  **hidden folder** from your solution folder.
or any other .git file