# Remove GitExtension context menu from vs2010

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010

I installed GitExtension and it bothers me every time I press the right button and the menu has some GitExt options.
I tried to use this thread to remove it: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141780/how-to-remove-hide-gitextensions-toolbar-from-visual-studio) but no success.
Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Git Extension, these button left on the context menu so I click it, got a message ask me if I want to remove the command which I accepted.